# How to Remove Spacing between HTML Component and LAbel

Tags: javascript, css

I have two radio Buttons as shown

```
container.insert('<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Date Range"/> Date Range');
container.insert('<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Duration"/> Duration ');
```

The issue is that , some space is being inserted between the Radio Buton and the label

Please see the output here

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=924d1b7

As you can see from this , Some space is being inserted between the Radio Button and the label Date Range

Comment: I would check out the CSS if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the css, but maybe this should fix the things right away:

```
<span><input type="radio" name="sex" id="Duration" value="Duration"/>
<label for="Duration">Duration</label></span>
```

It also sets the text as the label for the radio button, so you can click the text to change it, much easier than targeting the small radio button. Don't forget to add the "id" to the input

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the html and css of the page you're adding to, but at first glance, it looks like the other elements in the page are causing the container you're adding to to be made larger - try changing the size of tables / divs on the page  (and to verify this theory, try adding the same radio boxes to a blank page)

Comment: Nothing is working , The css used is #content {
   
    margin: 0px auto 22px;
    padding: 10px 0px 32px 0px;
    width: 900px;
}